# Select all items in a table that do not appear in a foreign key of another table

Tags: sql, mysql

Take for example an application which has users, each of which can be in exactly one group.  If we want to SELECT the list of groups which have no members, what would be the correct SQL?  I keep feeling like I'm just about to grasp the query, and then it disappears again.

Bonus points - given the alternative senario, where it's a many to many pairing, what is the SQL to identify unused groups?

(if you want concrete field names:)
One-To-Many:

```
Table 'users': | user_id | group_id |
Table 'groups': | group_id |
```

Many-To-Many:

```
Table 'users': | user_id |
Table 'groups': | group_id |
Table 'user-group': | user_id | group_id |
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers, they both do work.  I'm curious if there's any functional difference between the two methods.

Comment: @dimo414 - at least in Sql Server (2005), the execution plan for my version is shorter and has a *marginally* lower cost. Really, it'd be down to which one you consider more readable, unless you're using massive datasets! =)

Comment: However - having just run both queries in the same batch with 65,536 rows in users_groups, my query comes in at 1% of the batch cost and t'other one as 99% of the batch - both still executed in less than a second in total though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groups that have no members (for the many-many pairing):

```
SELECT *
FROM   groups g 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM users_groups ug 
      WHERE g.groupid = ug.groupid
    );
```

This Sql will also work in your "first" example as you can substitute "users" for "users_groups" in the sub-query =)

As far as performance is concerned, I know that this query can be quite performant on Sql Server, but I'm not so sure how well MySql likes it..

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM groups
LEFT JOIN users ON (groups.group_id=users.group_id)
WHERE users.user_id IS NULL;
```

For the second one, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM groups
LEFT JOIN user-group ON (groups.group_id=user-group.group_id)
WHERE user-group.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups
WHERE groups.id NOT IN (
    SELECT user.group_id 
    FROM user
)
```

It will return all group id which not present in user